# Ajax Submit form without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I hope someone could help me out with this.

First of all I do apologize if this question has already been asked. Before posting here I did go through all the relevant posts from where I have learnt a lot. But still I am struggling to make it work. The problem I have got is that whenever I press any button from the main .html page the php script seems to work fine (ie. if I press the left button my camera turns to the left) but soon after the .php page gets loaded into the browser as if I was navigating to it.

Please find below the code for the main .html file

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"             src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$("#newForm").on("submit", function(e){

    var $inputs = $('#newForm :input'),
        values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
      values[this.name] = this.value;
    });

    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : "mycamera.php",
      data: values,
      success : function(res) {
        $("#result").html(res);
        $("input[type=text]").val("");
      }
    });

    return false;
  });

    $(".back").on("click", function(){
    $("#result").html("");
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center><img src="http://192.168.1.70:8080/?action=stream" width="752"></center>
<form action="mycamera.php" method="post" id="newForm">
<div class="result"> </div>
<table
style="width: 75%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">Turn Camera Left/Right</td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">Turn Camera Up/Down</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><button name="Left">Left</button></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><button name="Up">Up</button></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><button name="RightIncrement">Right Increment</button>                </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><button name="Right">Right</button></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><button name="Down">Down</button></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><button name="LeftIncrement">Left Increment</button>  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align: center;"><button name="CentreLR">Centre L/R</button></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><button name="CentreUD">Centre U/D</button></td>
<td style="text-align: center;"><button name="Reboot">Reboot</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="form_result"> </div>   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the .php file:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['Left']))
{
exec('echo 1=60 > /dev/servoblaster');  
}
if (isset($_POST['Up']))  
{
exec('echo 0=60 > /dev/servoblaster');
}
if (isset($_POST['Right']))   
{
exec('echo 1=240 > /dev/servoblaster');
}
if (isset($_POST['Down']))
{
exec('echo 0=240 > /dev/servoblaster');
}
if (isset($_POST['CentreLR']))
{
exec('echo 1=150 > /dev/servoblaster');
}
if (isset($_POST['CentreUD']))
{
exec('echo 0=150 > /dev/servoblaster');
}
if (isset($_POST['RightIncrement']))
{
exec('echo 1=+10 > /dev/servoblaster');
}
if (isset($_POST['LeftIncrement']))
{
exec('echo 1=-10 > /dev/servoblaster');
}
if (isset($_POST['Reboot']))
{
exec('sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now');
}
?>
```

Many thanks in advance for your kind help!

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many edits that need to be made to your original code. The only change that we're making in the HTML is removing the form action -

HTML

```
<body>
    <center>
        <img src="http://192.168.1.70:8080/?action=stream" width="752">
    </center>
    <form action="" method="post" id="newForm">
        <div class="result"></div>
        <table style="width: 75%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">Turn Camera Left/Right</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">Turn Camera Up/Down</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <button name="Left">Left</button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <button name="Up">Up</button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <button name="RightIncrement">Right Increment</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <button name="Right">Right</button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <button name="Down">Down</button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <button name="LeftIncrement">Left Increment</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <button name="CentreLR">Centre L/R</button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <button name="CentreUD">Centre U/D</button>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">
                        <button name="Reboot">Reboot</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="form_result"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

In the PHP code we'll do a little tidy up, using a switch statement that is much more readable. We're testing `$_POST['action']` each time:

```
<?php
switch ($_POST['action']) {
  case 'Left':
    exec('echo 1=60 > /dev/servoblaster');  
    break;
  case 'Up':
    exec('echo 0=60 > /dev/servoblaster');
    break;
  case 'Right':
    exec('echo 1=240 > /dev/servoblaster');
    break;
  case 'Down':
    exec('echo 0=240 > /dev/servoblaster');
    break;
  case 'CentreLR':
    exec('echo 1=150 > /dev/servoblaster');
    break;
  case 'CentreUD':
    exec('echo 0=150 > /dev/servoblaster');
    break;
  case 'RightIncrement':
    exec('echo 1=+10 > /dev/servoblaster');
    break;
  case 'LeftIncrement':
    exec('echo 1=-10 > /dev/servoblaster');
    break;
  case 'Reboot':
    exec('sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now');
    break;    
} 
?>
```

Lastly the jQuery -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newForm').on('click', 'button', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).attr('name'); // get the button name
        console.log(action); // just for testing

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mycamera.php",
            data: {
                action: action // note that we're sending something that can be used in $_POST
            },
            success: function (res) {
                $("#result").html(res);
            }
        });
    });

    $(".back").on("click", function () {
        $("#result").html("");
    });
});
```

You were pretty close, but some syntax issues and some addition of inputs (you didn't have any in the form) that you tried to use as data for your PHP submission didn't exist. There was no form submission, but the button act the same as a submit and we were not stopping their default action.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the typo. Am I right in saying that ';' is missing after the last break case for reboot?

Comment: Even on a Pi there should be a browser console.

Comment: My apologies Jay. Did you mean the terminal session? If so what shall I check? Thanks

Comment: Are you accessing the interface in Epiphany?

Comment: No I am using my laptop via SSH

Comment: Look in the syslog on the Pi or in Apache's error log `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: I see thank you. I found 2 errors:Line 2 was ']' instead of')' and line 3 it says"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'case' (T_CASE) in /var/www/myrobot.php on line 3," which I can't figure that out. Please note that I have renamed the php file to my robot.php. Thanks

Comment: I made a correction which should also cure the problem with line 3. I forgot the closing ']' in `switch ($_POST['action']) {`

Comment: You are my hero Jay that did the trick. I also found that ':' was missing at another line (soon after 'LeftIncrement' at line 24). Now everything is working great!!! Many thanks again for your big help!!!!Very much appreciated. Unfortunately I can't vote up as I need 15 reputations for that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop the form submission from triggering and you are also not waiting for the dom to fully load before binding events to elements. So, replace your `<script>` with this:

```
<script>
    // wait for the DOM to fully load
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#newForm").on("submit", function(e) {
            // disable the default action
            e.preventDefault();
            var $inputs = $('#newForm :input'),
                    values = {};
            $inputs.each(function() {
                values[this.name] = this.value;
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mycamera.php",
                data: values,
                success: function(res) {
                    $("#result").html(res);
                    $("input[type=text]").val("");
                }
            });

            return false;
        });

        $(".back").on("click", function() {
            $("#result").html("");
        });
    })
</script>
```

More info about `preventDefault` [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). More info about `.ready` [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for getting back to me. I have just tried but it didn't work.The .php page gets loaded.

Comment: If what you have posted is your full code, I see no reason for this behaviour. I'd suggest taking albertone74's advice and use something other than the submit event.

Comment: Yes that's my full code.Sorry I am not a big expert. Would you mind explaining to me what I could use instead? Many thanks.

Comment: Hi,thanks I have tried that. Still no luck at all. Any more suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wrap your event listener inside a $(document).ready(function(){ //your code }); Or place your script tag after the form element. 
Issue is when your script runs, it first executes the event binding then render the #newForm DOM object. To overcome this you need to make sure DOM elements are already loaded to the browser before binding events.

Secondly you need to add  e.preventDefault(); to avoid page refresh (default form submission event).

Try it like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#newForm").on("submit", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       //your code
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried that but with no luck at all. Thanks.